# xml request gets convert to text/html request and causing 500 internal server error?

Tags: php, ajax, xml, wordpress, .htaccess

i am sending a ajax request and expecting xml response but the response gets converted to text/html  .It is causing 500 internal server error too.the same code is working on my localhost.
[image]

below is a small code which shows how i am sending  the request

```
var searchUrl = '<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/phpsqlsearch_genxml-new-home-page.php?address=' + address + '&postal_code=' + postal_code + '&radius=' + radius + '&suggestion=' + suggestion;
    downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
        var xml = parseXml(data);
        var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        if (markerNodes.length == 0)    /////////////check empty result/////////////
        {
        var msg = jQuery("<div/>").html("aucun r&eacute;sultat trouv&eacute;").text();
        alert(msg);

        displayAllStoresOfbrands();
        }
```

and below is the code of the file i am hitting my ajax request

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/xml");
```

above is the code which i have placed on the top of my ajax file

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the content-type of a 500 response is text/html, unless you specifically override that for a 500 response.

Likely, there is a different issue that manifests itself with your code deployed to the server. That issue is causing the 500 response.

To quickly diagnose this, you could just try wrapping your php code for the ajax response in a try catch, and return an error message.  If you do this, the error message will be the "cause" of the original 500 response, and your new ajax response should be a 200 response of the proper content-type.